# Click to change between 2 function jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, toggle

The `toggle()` method was deprecated in jQuery version 1.8, and removed in version 1.9. [Documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_event_toggle)

How can use something like `toggle()` function in jQuery 1.11+ ?

Full Code in [Fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/2y1kr4wa/13/)

```
<script>
    function test(){
        $("*:contains(ไทย):last").text("English");
    }
    function test2(){
        $("*:contains(English):last").text("ไทย");
    }

    $("#click").toggle(
        test(),
        test2();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: https://fiddle.jshell.net/2y1kr4wa/19/

Comment: Have a look at this [toggleClick](https://github.com/maniator/jQuery-toggleClick/blob/master/jquery-toggleclick.js)

Comment: yurzui It's Work. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know about this behaviour, but there is my solution:

```
function test(){
    $("*:contains(ไทย):last").text("English");
}
function test2(){
    $("*:contains(English):last").text("ไทย");
}

var el = document.getElementById("click");
$(el).click(function (e) {
    el.foo.apply(this, arguments);
});

el.foo = test;
el.toggle = function () {
    el.foo = el.foo === test ? test2 : test;
};
```